# Почему в консоль выводятся лишние символы?

Tags: c++, char

Написал такой код:

```
char line[100], muteLine[100], symbol;
    int len, muteIndex = 0;
    cout << "Введите строку: ";                         cin >> line;     cout << endl;
    cout << "Введите символ, который надо удалить: ";   cin >> symbol;   cout << endl;
    len = strlen(line);
    for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        if (line[i] != symbol) {
            muteLine[muteIndex] = line[i];
            muteIndex++;
        }
    }

    cout << muteLine;
```

Стояла такая задача:

> Из предложения удалить все символы, совпадающие с символом, введенным
>   с клавиатуры.

Но по какой-то причине в консоль вылазят лишние символы, с чем это связано?
[image: ing]

Comment: @avp, напишите в  ответ, все работает :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не заносите терминатор `\0` в конец формируемой в цикле строки `muteLine[]`, поэтому `cout << muteLine;` читает и выводит случайное содержимое памяти уже за `muteLine[]`.

После цикла добавьте `muteLine[muteIndex] = 0;` (или в цикле двигайтесь до `len + 1`)
(кстати, сейчас вы не проверяете последний символ в `line[]`).